# How to split angular material table columns in to multiple pages (pagination)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a material table with dynamic number of columns.

Lets assume there are 20 columns of data to be displayed.

For each page, it should display 5 columns. When user click on the pagination, it should display the other columns.

How to achieve this with Angular material table and pagination ?

Comment: Mainly pagination is used to show next set of rows, why do you wanna show next set of columns in pagination ?

Comment: It would be easier to give you advice if you prepared a stackblitz example. But the short version - this can't be done with the mat-paginator as it bind to the DataSource and cares about rows and not columns.But it should be fairly easy to handle on your own. Just have a collection of  `allColumns` and add two buttons that will change the contents of the `displayedColumns` for your table. You can style it similarly to the mat-paginator as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paginator itself give you an index from 0 to number of pages. The only thing you need is change the displayColumns taking account this index.

If you has, e.g. a paginator like

```
<mat-paginator #paginator [length]="7" hidePageSize="true" 
           (page)="changeDisplayColumns($event)"
           [pageSize]="2">
</mat-paginator>
```

and a variable with all the columns

```
displayedColumnsAll: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 
                                 'symbol',"another","another2","another3"];
```

See that in `[length]`of paginator you put the quantity of columns (in the e.g."7")

You can do

```
  changeDisplayColumns(page:PageEvent)
  {
    this.displayedColumns=this.displayedColumnsAll.slice(
          page.pageIndex*page.pageSize,
          page.pageIndex*page.pageSize+page.pageSize)
  }
```

See a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7zhpt4?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

NOTE: At first you need give value to displayedColums with index=0, see the

```
displayedColumns=this.displayedColumnsAll.slice(0,2)
```

in the stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I think the demo from [angular material demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/omaaqabvdad?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-dynamic-columns-example.ts) here will be fit your requirement.

It not call pagination but let call it dynamically column.

You can implement a button name `next column page` and do the action by adding some and removing some columns when clicked.